# Ubuntu hangs before boot

Tags: boot

So, basically I encountered the error when the power went off. I tried to turn on the computer and hit enter to start Ubuntu but the power cut off again. Upon booting, then several boots later the PC won't even boot Ubuntu at all. (The PC is dual-booted with Windows 8 and Ubuntu.) The machine hangs as soon as you hit enter to start Ubuntu, but Windows boots fine. When the PC hangs, the screen is entirely purple, the same shade of purple that GRUB uses. Is there any way to fix this?

PC info:
Helwett-Packard, model QW811AAR#ABC

Comment: Try burning `boot-info` (found on the Ubuntu Community site -- community.ubuntu.com) to a USB stick or disk and running that.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Ok, I'll try that. I'm downloading it right now.

Comment: Oops. I meant boot repair. I'm glad you figured out what I meant.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I just googled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I was able to boot the machine by selecting Advanced options for Ubuntu and attempting to boot it in normal mode with a different kernel.